# Why can't I find a pure representation of a PCA loading in my dataset

Tags: pca

Perhaps I don't fully understand the PCA principles...I am applying PCA to spectroscopic data. I get a nice loading that beautifully explains 1 component in my dataset, however I cannot find this pure component spectrum (representative of this loading) in my dataset. Or does the loading just explain a trend without it actually being present in the dataset in a pure (unmixed) form.
Up til now I was always able to find this pure spectrum from the scores plot but perhaps I was lucky with previous data sets.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about optics, but keep in mind that PCA doesn't know anything about optics, either. It is a pretty low-level bit of linear algebra that works by recoding the data into high-variance but uncorrelated components. It comes with no guarantees that the first few principal components will have any substantive meaning. This will only happen to the degree that substantive relationships give rise to shared variance.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response...the thing is that the loading very nicely overlays with my pure component spectrum. In the past, it has allowed me to 'find' these low concentration components in my mixture...as pure spectra. Perhaps I was just lucky?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about your field to really understand what you're talking about. You'd need to talk to somebody who's familiar with the substantive issues or give me a crash course in spectroscopy. But yes, perhaps you were just lucky in the past.